# How to create a new site (locale: de-AT) based on another site (de) within same installation?

Tags: craft3, localization, migration, language

I manage a website with multiple languages. Each language has its own site and domain. Think: website.de and website.co.uk

I have to add another site with different locale (de-AT) to the Craft CMS installation. It should run on website.at

- The Austrian site should be initialized exactly the same as the current German (de) site.
- Afterwards some content will be edited but the foundation but the base should be the same (around 1000 entries).

What would be the best way to 'clone' the German website within the installation to the Austrian website?

It would be okay to manually configure all Sections but I don't want to add every entry manually.

Answer (score 1):

Think if the de site is the default site and the sections are setup to propagate the entries to other sites with the same language (or within the same site group, if de and de-AT will be in the same site group), the entries should be copied to the new de-AT site.